# ESP8266 NodeMCU Multiple libraries were found for "SD.h" error

Tags: compiler-errors, arduino, header, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I have only this imports of code to controls some leds with Firebase
But when i compile i got the error message regarding the sh.h in multiple locations
i put the error down below.

```
#include <FirebaseESP8266.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
```

error message

```
Multiple libraries were found for "SD.h"
 Used: /Users/user1/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.0/libraries/SD
 Not used: /Users/user1/Desktop/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries/SD
exit status 127
Error compiling for board NodeMCU 0.9 (ESP-12 Module).
```

I dont know why is the sd.h header is been called but im getting this error.

Comment: Please switch on extended Debug ArduinoIDE->File->Preferences->Compiler warnings->ALL then after compiling scroll to top of the compiler output  and look at the first warning/error probably a missing bracket or semi colon somewhere. Remove any warnings/errors. If you  need further helppaste the all warnings/errors to your question AND your relevant code

Comment: this is not the cause